# How to terminate Google App Engine Deployment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-managed-vm

I have a Google compute engine instance on which I was trying the [Google Cloud + Node.js tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-datastore). And I accidentally entered the following command:

```
gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --set-default
```

Accidentally because I want to run the node.js deployment directly from my compute engine instance (which I'm now doing) instead of spinning up a GAE deployment. So the problem is that I see 2 GAE VM instances that have been spun up to manage this app. And I'm at my wits end as to how to terminate them - Simply terminating the instances from the Dev Console just spins up new ones.

Any idea how to terminate the GAE deployment? (I'm still using the same project for my compute engine app)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `vm: true` field in your config and redeploy. This will switch your app's deployment type from [Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/config) to Google App Engine.

Google App Engine app will scale down to 0 instances if not used because they have very low startup time, whereas Managed VMs run on VMs and do not scale down to zero because of the higher startup latency.

You can also [delete previous versions via Google Developers Console](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/developers-console/#versions).